# How to access and modify a web config file of a project hosted in different server using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I am developing an application which can change the password of a sql server user ,if sql databse admin username and password are provided

here is the code

```
string Connt = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ToString();

SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(Connt);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader;

string newone = "pwd";
string username = "username";

cmd.CommandText = "alter login " + username + " with password = '" + newone + "' old_password= '" + old + "' ";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Then i need to change this sql user password in the connection string in web config file of the application which uses the same user.

```
string path = "path";
ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
map.ExeConfigFilename = path;

Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

string connStr_App = config.AppSettings.Settings["ConnectionString"].Value;
config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("ConnectionString");
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("ConnectionString", "conectionstringwithnewpassword");
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

so far its working fine.
But the problem is that i can only change the web config file of an application that hosted in the same machine.

I need to change a web config file of an application which hosted in different server,assuming i have the admin password and username.

This link seems useful 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228054%28v=vs.100%29.aspx 
but my application needs administrative privileges on that remote server.How to attain that? right now its showing access denied  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) message.
 I activated  remote configuration component on server by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry it was an error in my code
just followed as in below code.
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228054%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To access the configuration on the other machine, I'm guessing you will need some kind of service running there to allow this update to happen (or FTP).  I don't think there is a simple way to do this remotely (for good reason).

You also need to look at the massive SQL injection vulnerability in your code... It's not hard to fix, particularly necessary if you are running with admin credentials against the box:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx