# Change a web.config of remote server programmatically with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2

How can I modify/manipulate the web.config of remote server programmatically with C# using credentials to connect that remote server?

Can I use a ConnectionOptions object, and, if yes, how can I load the web.config into a local file? I would like to have a full example of connecting remote server and copying web.config from the remote server's M drive to a local file. After the modification, the web.config should be written back to the remote server's config file.

I have written below code to connect to remote server and I'm able to connect it. Could you please guide what should be the next step?

```
string serverName = "ipaddress";

ConnectionOptions connection = new ConnectionOptions();
connection.Username = "uname";
connection.Password = "pwd$";

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + serverName + @"\root\cimv2", connection);
scope.Connect();
```

After this I want to read file which is on remote server's location like 'M:\Test\App\config'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access and modify a web config file of a project hosted in different server using asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656583/how-to-access-and-modify-a-web-config-file-of-a-project-hosted-in-different-serv)

Comment: @nilsK This won't answer the O.P question since this question pertains to .NET CORE 2.2

Comment: @RahulSharma my bad! Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Doesn't that M drive have a share? That would be much easier because then you can use normal File classes and open `@"\\"+serverName+"\M$\TestApp\config"` with the only challenge to switch credentials. WMI doesn't look like it will allow for readimg or writing the file.